# Cursor with -1 parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been trying to query employees using the cursor with the parameter however I want to retrieve all the data without passing a value into the parameter, any ideas?

```
    DECLARE

   cursor emp_cursor(v_dept_id number) IS
    SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE department_id = v_dept_id;
    
    
BEGIN 
    FOR emp_record IN emp_cursor(60) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(' id = ' || emp_record.employee_id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I need to use -1 to fetch for all the data in a certain department but using -1 as a value in a parameter

Comment: If the cursor requires a parameter then you have to provide one. A query with different predicates (or no predicates) would require a different cursor.

Comment: @pmdba How can i pass a parameter of 60 (so that it retrieves al the data for that department id) and if the user passed -1 then it retrieves all the data in the table regardless the department_id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `-1` to represent wanting all values then you can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  cursor emp_cursor(v_dept_id number) IS
    SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE department_id = v_dept_id
    OR    v_dept_id = -1;
BEGIN 
  FOR emp_record IN emp_cursor(-1) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(' id = ' || emp_record.employee_id);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, department_id) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

```
 id = 1
 id = 2
 id = 3
 id = 4
 id = 5
 id = 6
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LvNCehoJ)

Comment: Thank you MT0, Could you please explain what's the logic behind v_dept_id = -1 AS there's no dep_id = -1

Comment: @MoustafaYoussef You are either finding the values where the `department_id` matches the parameter value passed to the cursor (i.e. `department_id = v_dept_id`) or you are finding any `department_id` where the parameter value is -1 (i.e. `v_dept_id = -1` and in this case the value of `department_id` is not compared to anything).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok - just change the where clause like below. It covers all options of passing v_dept_id - if it is Null or -1 you'll get all the records - otherways just for department passed to the cursor:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    CURSOR emp_cursor(v_dept_id NUMBER) IS
    SELECT * FROM emp
--  below is the where clause handling all of the options
    WHERE DEPTNO = CASE Nvl(v_dept_id, -1) WHEN -1 THEN DEPTNO ELSE v_dept_id END;
BEGIN 
    FOR emp_record IN emp_cursor(10) LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(' id = ' || emp_record.empno);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Results for passed values:

| emp_cursor(Null) Or (-1) | emp_cursor(10) |
| --- | --- |
| id = 7939 | id = 7939 |
| id = 7369 | id = 7369 |
| id = 7499 | id = 7782 |
| id = 7521 | id = 7839 |
| id = 7566 | id = 7902 |
| id = 7654 | id = 7934 |
| id = 7698 |  |
| id = 7782 |  |
| id = 7788 |  |
| id = 7839 |  |
| id = 7844 |  |
| id = 7876 |  |
| id = 7900 |  |
| id = 7902 |  |
| id = 7934 |  |

Note: Old emp table here - adjust it to yours